# How can I connect to a server port in Excel PowerQuery

Tags: mysql, database, excel, port

I was able to connect to the mysql server using Excel PowerQuery. But the problem is if I have to connect to two different ports of the same server, I was unable to do that. Could some please let me know how to do this?

Thanks,
Venu

Comment: You need to tell us what you've tried and maybe paste some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port by adding a colon after the server name and then adding the port number, like this:

*server*:*port number*

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it throughs an error.

DataSource.Error: MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Details: Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ErrorCode=-2147467259

it works with server name but not with server name and port. please let me know the steps if i am wrong in doing it.

Thanks, Venu